# Not able to read the error log

Tags: powershell

My below script will genrate Error log when we have some error in the ZIP file. Zip file should cosnsist of three file if any one is missing the run.bat throw an Error.log file.
I intentionaly made a missing file in ZIP and the script should generat an error.log, but the script is throwing that the Error.log file is blank.
When I tried with break point the script is workking properly and getting mail as there is an error, if I disbale the break point and run it will not send mail. What is wrong in the script. Thank you for your support.

```
$errorlog = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\error.log"
$emailconnecter_log = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\connector.log"

#1  print "Running email bat file...... \n";
Write-Host "Running email bat file...... \n"
$prog="cmd.exe"
$params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log')
start-process $prog $params -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus" -RedirectStandardOutput $emailconnecter_log
    #$rc = & D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat > $emailconnecter_log
    if (-not $?) 
    { 
    Write-Host $rc
        $status = "running Daily email bat file failed on $hostname"
        Del_Daily
        Del_Dat
        Send_Mail
        exit
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host $rc
    Write-Host "Email send sucess fully....."
    }

###check for email error log
If (Test-Path $errorlog)
{
$content =  Get-Content $errorlog 
Write-Host "File is not blank"
    Write-Host "File is not blank"
    foreach ($line in $content)
    {
        Write-Host $line
        IF ($line | Select-String -Quiet -Pattern '^\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sERROR')
        {
            Write-Host $line "Done"
            $status = "Daily Email Connector Has ERRORS in the log." 
            $body = "Check $hostname\logs or $archive_location "
            Write-Host $status `n $body
            # Send_Mail
            $rc = Copy-Item $errorlog $archive_location
            $rc = Copy-Item $emailconnecter_log $archive_location           
            Del_Daily
            Del_Dat
            exit
        }
        else{Write-Host "No Error message"}
    }
}
else{Write-Host "File is blank"}
```

Comment: You have functions we cannot see what they (`Del_Daily`,`Del_Dat`,`Send_Mail`)  are doing and from what I can tell nowhere here to you send data to `$errorlog`

Comment: These function are simple functions and its not making any issue. The `$errorlog –` will generate in the Run.bat

Comment: My question is it requrie any command to release the writing the error in error.log filelby using run.dat int he below code`$prog="cmd.exe"
$params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log')
start-process $prog $params -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus" -RedirectStandardOutput $emailconnecter_log`

Comment: All you are giving us to work with is that the `$errorlog` is empty. We _now_ know that it comes from `run.bat`. We have no idea how the log is populated. You are redirecting std out to the other log. Are the error lines contained in that file?

Comment: Your understanding is correct , `run.bat` will generate the error log and the std out is not for Error.log. The `run.bat` is calling some jar file which will triger the email functionality, if we have some issue in email triggering then `run.bat` will genreate Error.log with some error messge. I hope now you understand my question